# Choice of foods and proportions for vegans

Tags: nutrition, diet, hospital, vegan

Relating to the average patient's meal, which foods and how would the portion size be modified in order to meet [Dietary Guidelines](https://food-guide.canada.ca/en/guidelines/).

EDIT: In other words, what to think about when designing vegan meals in hospitals?

Comment: Nutrition questions are on topic here only when they're directly related to medical treatments. You mention "average patients" but what is an average patient? And what do vegans have to do with this? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I consider 'the average patient' to be more stable or closer to normal in terms of health, such as any patient in a long-term care facility.

Comment: I'm very hesitant as to whether this should be on topic but at a minimum you should edit those stipulations into the question.

Comment: You linked to Canada's Dietary Guidelines, but can you link directly to a page that says which foods patterns (macronutrient percentages, daily amounts of nutrients) these guidelines recommend.

Comment: I haven't found this information specifically yet, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Impossible, given the current abysmal catering service at hospitals. Portion sizes are extremely small, patients need to eat the fatty sausages served to avoid malnutrition. A healthier menu would have larger portion sizes of vegetables, starches, whole grains and smaller pieces of meat, and smaller amounts if fat. But to get to healthy vegan meals, the portion sizes would need to be much larger still, there is no way one can do that in any realistic hospital setting currently in existence.

Comment: @CountIblis, if it's possible to have healthy vegan meals at home, it's also possible to have them in hospitals. It does depend on a hospital, but this can be all realistic.

Comment: @CountIblis At least at three hospitals in the US that I'm personally familiar with your statement about patients being forced to eat "fatty sausages to avoid malnutrition" is entirely false. If you're going to make statements like that, provide evidence to support them.

Comment: @CareyGregory [See here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4596423/), the amount of calories patients get in hospital is too low even for old and frail people.

Comment: @CountIblis I'm familiar with the problem but the paper doesn't say it's because patients aren't given enough food. That was pure hyperbole on your part. It's inadequate nutrition management among sick, frail people, not a lack of food.

Comment: B12 deficiency is something vegans should definitely watch out for (less relevant to short stays at the hospital)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [2019 Canada's Dietary Guidelines](https://food-guide.canada.ca/static/assets/pdf/CDG-EN-2018.pdf) - full version for professionals (easy to read, references to scientific evidence).

[Recommended intakes for **macronutrients**](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/food-nutrition/healthy-eating/dietary-reference-intakes/tables/reference-values-macronutrients-dietary-reference-intakes-tables-2005.html) in a 2,000 Calorie/day diet: *(RDA = Recommended Dietary Allowance is the amount that should be sufficient for most adults ; AMDR = Acceptable Macronutrient Distribution Range (in % of total energy intake)*; links to vegan foods included:

- **[Carbohydrate](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=205&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m):** RDA: 130 g/day ; AMDR: 45-65% of total energy

  - [Fiber](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=291&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m): 21-30 g/day
  - [Free sugars](https://www.choosemyplate.gov/what-are-added-sugars) (in fruit juices or added as in sweetened beverages): <10% of total energy (<50 g)
- **[Protein](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=203&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m):** RDA = 0.80 g/kg body weigh/day (56 g/70 kg man; 46 g/58 kg woman); AMDR = 10-35% of total energy
- **[Fat](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=204&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m):** AMDR = 20-35% of total energy

  - [Saturated fat](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=606&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m): <10% total energy (<20 g/day)
  - [Trans fat](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=605&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m): <1% total energy (<2 g/day)

Recommended intakes for **micronutrients:**

- [Minerals](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/food-nutrition/healthy-eating/dietary-reference-intakes/tables/reference-values-elements-dietary-reference-intakes-tables-2005.html)
- [Vitamins](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/food-nutrition/healthy-eating/dietary-reference-intakes/tables/reference-values-vitamins-dietary-reference-intakes-tables-2005.html)

An "average meal" in a hospital can refer to a healthy meal intended for an omnivore person with no special dietary needs. Vegan meals in hospitals, which do not contain meat, fish, eggs and milk, should contain enough iron and protein from plant sources.

[Plant foods rich in **iron** (USDA.gov)](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=303&nutrient2=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m):

- Beans, peas, lentils
- Cereals ready-to-eat (fortified)
- Sunflower and pumpkin seeds
- Nuts: cashew, pine
- Lupins
- Spinach
- Grains: amaranth, barley, cornmeal, kamut, oats, quinoa, rye, semolina, shorghum, spelt
- Beets
- Dried figs

[Plant foods high in **protein** (>10 g/serving) and low in fat (<10 g/serving)(USDA.gov)](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/report/nutrientsfrm?max=25&offset=0&totCount=0&nutrient1=203&nutrient2=204&nutrient3=&fg=8&fg=20&fg=9&fg=16&fg=12&fg=11&subset=0&sort=c&measureby=m):

- Lupins
- Beans, lentils and peas (most types)
- Grains: cornmeal, quinoa, spelt, triticale
- Fermented soy: hummus, tempeh, tofu

Foods high in protein but also in fat include most nuts and seeds.

Maybe the most appropriate beverages are those that are low in sugar: plain or mineral water, vegetable juices, tea.

Vegan patients who stay in a hospital for several months may also benefit from vitamin D and B12 supplements.

When designing vegan meals in hospitals, one can use the info from USDA Food Composition Database, linked above.

Comment: Thank you for detailing in your response!

Comment: @aitía, I've found the full version of Canada's Dietary Guidelines and I included recommended amounts of macronutrients.